# Pass result of AJAX search form to a different view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I can almost always find an answer searching stack overflow, but after many hours, I have come up blank. I am sure that I am doing something that should be easy, but complicating it for myself.

I have an "orders" index view with an AJAX search, sort and pagination. It's all set up based on [this screen cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax?view=asciicast). Works fine.

However, I would like my users to be able to click a link to another page, which will be set up to print the results of the search, without the navigation, pagination, etc.

It seems the best way to do this is to have the new view perform the same search as was already performed on the index page.

I have created another route, action and view called print_list that is basically the same as the index page, but without the pagination, etc. Not very DRY, but for the purposes of this mockup, it's acceptable.

The question is how do I pass the AJAX search parameters to the other view? Basically, I need to pass the params into the link_to helper. 
So for example:

`<%=link_to "Print List", print_list_orders_path(:cat =>"name ", :search => "er", :range => "Forever") %>`

renders:

`<a href="/orders/print_list?cat=name+&amp;range=Forever&amp;search=er">Print List</a>`

...and that works fine, and passes those parameters. What I need is a way to be dynamically updating those params as the AJAX calls are made, and the Index page is updated. I could write a jQuery bit using:

`$('.myLink').attr('href','/orders/print_list?cat=name+&amp;range=Forever&amp;search=er">');`

and call it everytime the AJAX updates.(of course I would have to add the CSS class for that, obviously) However, that does not seem like the best way to do this, what with the hard coded path and all. Is there a more Railsy way? 
I was also thinking that later in my development process, I wouldn't mind being able to save searches, so a method that could also be used to save the search for reuse later gets extra points. 
Thanks for reading!

Comment: I'm thinking the jQuery way might not be that bad, considering I already have the serialized data from the form in my javascript, and I could just append it to the url, so I'd still be using the path helper. Still I'd like to hear thoughts on classier ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever has this problem - the solution is to use the rails session method, and store the search in the session.